# how to download an excel and return some error message from spring controller on clicking a link on jsp

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

There are one textarea, one button and one div(to display error message) on jsp page.

When click the button, according to the text in textarea,if the input text in textarea is not correct,then display error message in div.if all is ok,then download the excel.

When I input incorrect text in the textarea, the error message is displayed.
When I input correct text in the textarea, I can not download excel, it directly display PK�R�P[Content_Types].xml�S�n�0����*6�PU�C���{�X�%����]8�R� q�cfgfW�d�q�ZCB|��|�*�*h 
...
...
on web page

index.jsp

```
...
<textarea class="boxsizingBorder" id="activities"></textarea>
<button onclick="showresult()">download</button>
<div class="instruction"  id="process_result"></div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showresult() {
        document.getElementById("process_result").innerHTML = "process...";
        document.getElementById("process_result").style.color = 'gray';
        var activities = document.getElementById('activities').value;
        var querycontent = JSON.stringify({
            "activities" : activities
        });
    
        $
                .ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'showresult', 
                    contentType : 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    data : querycontent,
                    dataType : 'html',
                    success : function(msg) {
                        document.getElementById("process_result").innerHTML = msg;
                        document.getElementById("process_result").style.color = 'red';
                    },
                    error : function() {
                        document.getElementById("process_result").innerHTML = "download failed!";
                        document.getElementById("process_result").style.color = 'red';
                    }
                })
    }
</script>
```

MonitorController.java

```
@Controller
public class MonitorController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showresult", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody String showResult(@RequestBody QueryData querycontent, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {
        DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
        String message = "";
        String activities = querycontent.getactivities();
        System.out.println("origin activities:\n" + activities);
        String pattern = "^[0-9\\n]+$";
        boolean isMatch = Pattern.matches(pattern, activities);
        if (isMatch == false) {
            message = "please input correct character!";
        } else {
            activities = activities.replaceAll("^[\\n]+", "");
            System.out.println("activities delete first newlines:\n" + activities);
            activities = activities.replaceAll("[\\n]+$", "");
            System.out.println("activities delete last newlines:\n" + activities);
            activities = activities.replaceAll("[\\n]+", ",");
            System.out.println("activities2:\n" + activities);
            ArrayList<String[]> MonitorList = dbcon.getImpAndClk(activities);
            String[][] monitorArray = (String[][]) MonitorList.toArray(new String[0][0]);
            if (monitorArray.length == 0) {
                message = "no result";
            } else {

                String filename = "filename.xls";
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                        "attachment;filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8"));

                Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); // new HSSFWorkbook() for generating `.xls` file
                /*
                 * CreationHelper helps us create instances of various things like DataFormat,
                 * Hyperlink, RichTextString etc, in a format (HSSF, XSSF) independent way
                 */
                CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
                // Create a Sheet
                Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee");

                // Create a Font for styling header cells
                Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
                headerFont.setBold(true);
                headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
                headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
                // Create a CellStyle with the font
                CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

                String[] headerTitle = { "ID1", "ID2"};
                // Create a Row
                Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
                // Create header cells
                for (int i = 0; i < headerTitle.length; i++) {
                    Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
                    cell.setCellValue(headerTitle[i]);
                    cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
                }

                workbook.write(response.getOutputStream()); // Write workbook to response.
                
                
                // Closing the workbook
                workbook.close();

            }
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'v resolved it.
add another requestmapping method in MonitorController.java

```
@Controller
public class MonitorController {
    private String activities = "";
    private DBConnection dbcon = null;
    private ArrayList<String[]> MonitorList = null;
    private String[][] monitorArray = null;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showresult", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody String showResult(@RequestBody QueryData querycontent, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {
        dbcon = new DBConnection();
        String message = "";
        activities = querycontent.getactivities();
        System.out.println("origin activities:\n" + activities);
        String pattern = "^[0-9\\n]+$";
        boolean isMatch = Pattern.matches(pattern, activities);
        if (isMatch == false) {
            message = "please input correct character!";
        } else {
            activities = activities.replaceAll("^[\\n]+", "");
            System.out.println("activities delete first newlines:\n" + activities);
            activities = activities.replaceAll("[\\n]+$", "");
            System.out.println("activities delete last newlines:\n" + activities);
            activities = activities.replaceAll("[\\n]+", ",");
            System.out.println("activities2:\n" + activities);
            MonitorList = dbcon.getImpAndClk(activities);
            monitorArray = (String[][]) MonitorList.toArray(new String[0][0]);
            if (monitorArray.length == 0) {
                message = "no result";
            } else {
            }
        }
        return message;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void downloadLicenseFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("activities in download controller:\n" + activities);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmm");
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
        String filename = "filename.xls";
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8"));

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); // new HSSFWorkbook() for generating `.xls` file
        /*
         * CreationHelper helps us create instances of various things like DataFormat,
         * Hyperlink, RichTextString etc, in a format (HSSF, XSSF) independent way
         */
        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        // Create a Sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("SheetName");

        // Create a Font for styling header cells
        Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
        headerFont.setBold(true);
        headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        // Create a CellStyle with the font
        CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

        String[] headerTitle = { "ID1", "ID2"};
        // Create a Row
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
        // Create header cells
        for (int i = 0; i < headerTitle.length; i++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellValue(headerTitle[i]);
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
        }
        workbook.write(response.getOutputStream()); // Write workbook to response.
        // Closing the workbook
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
success : function(msg) {
                        document.getElementById("process_result").innerHTML = msg;
                        document.getElementById("process_result").style.color = 'red';
                        if (msg == "") {
                            window.location.href = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/download';
                        }
                    },
```